# Selenium RC failing to retrieve or timing out on page load.

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-rc, junit4

I exported a working Selenium test case to Java, running it via selenium-rc's selenium-server.jar in Junit4 on Eclipse.

The test case breaks the next step after opening the page, trying to write to an element.  When stepping through the runtime I noticed the error,

> > **The requested URL could not be retrieved**
> >
> > The following error was encountered:
> >
> > Unable to determine IP address from host name for unknown server name
> >
> > This means that: The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL.  Check if the address is correct.

So, I changed the url to the corresponding IP address of the web page, but now I am timing out.

Opening the page using both the url and IP formats manually is working, (except IP doesn't for IE8).  I'm originally targeting Firefox, but will expand to other browsers once I have solved this issue.

Is there a security issue involved with Selenium opening a page in a browser via RC programatically that browsers don't like?  What sort of issues should I be investigating to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually came down to the proxy set up on my machine.  After removing it things worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to open a secure page.In selenium pages which has ssl certificates should be handled.